# MSAL/B2C error: 'Secure Connection Failed' AFTER getting valid ID token

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

***Short Summary:***

I have an Angular 7.0 front-end client using MSAL-angular.js library to authenticate with a .NET CORE API application. Both are hosted on Azure using B2C.

The call below returns a valid ID token in the URL, but then the following errors (minor difference in each browser):

**A. Chrome:**

> This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid
>   response.  ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

**B. Firefox**

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:4200.  SSL received
>   a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.  Error code:
>   SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

**C. IE**

> Can’t connect securely to this page This might be because the site
>   uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings.

***Detailed steps:***

1. Client authenticates in MyAuth.service.ts

```js
import { MsalService, BroadcastService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
// unrelated code...
export class MyAuthService{
constructor(private http: HttpClient, 
private authService : MsalService,  
private broadcastService: BroadcastService,
private httpService: HttpServiceHelper) { }

public loginMSAL() {
this.authService.loginPopup(["openid", "offline_access",
"https://myBusinessName.onmicrosoft.com/api-dev/user_impersonation"]).  
then(function (idToken: any) {
  console.log("token: "+idToken); //This never gets hit.
});
console.log("...exit loginMSAL()..."); //
}
```

2. The popup comes up to login a user, with this URL (the "04d8c97b" ID is my **Azure B2C tenant ID**, mybusinessname.onmicrosoft.com) :

```html
https://login.microsoftonline.com/04d8c97b-23df-4533-b5fe-197f0117556c/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?response_type=id_token
&scope=offline_access
%20https%3A%2F%2Fmybusinessname.onmicrosoft.com
%2Fapi-dev
%2Fuser_impersonation
%20openid
%20profile
&client_id=0af5e22c-1233-470f-b2a8-e47038c69524 //This is my angular web client's ID on Azure.
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F
&state=c5a0006a-80f0-4d25-9eeb-49ddd0bc292b
&nonce=2699ca31-52f3-455b-9906-137772f2f0a8
&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS
&x-client-Ver=0.2.1
&client-request-id=d9eed293-c1bd-4f75-a824-dc0bfe956c17
&prompt=select_account
&response_mode=fragment
&sso_reload=true
```

2.a) The login pop-up seems to work fine. 
     It shows the account name I've logged in previously, testUser1@mybusinessname.onmicrosoft.com.

2.b) Entering the password works fine, THEN pain starts.

3. The popup window gives the errors above, but the URL changes to the following, showing a valid ID token has been obtained. URL is:

> https://localhost:4200/#id_token=eyJ0e ...long token here...
>
> &state=26deef89-94db-49ec-94a6-fbb6e7f93f13
>
> &session_state=ca5489a4-842a-48f2-9fa5-7b85a1582d55

4. Putting the token into jwt.ms, it looks valid:

```js
 {
      "typ": "JWT",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "kid": "nbCwW11w3XkB-xUaXwKRjLjMHGQ"
    }.{
      "aud": "0af5e22c-1233-470f-b2a8-e47038c69524",
      "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/04d8c97b-25df-4533-b5fe-197f0117556c/v2.0", *//This is the ID for my Azure B2C Tenant, 'mybusinessname.onmicrosoft.com'*
      "iat": 1545600536,
      "nbf": 1545600536,
      "exp": 1545604436,
      "aio": "ATQAy/8JAAAARe1ST0VN1rzLio14LI4Y6B6VcY1nPurvB2G+FOWLjs/3QtkQdiHfRVnpgw6Ohm/2",
      "name": "TestUser1",
      "nonce": "ee43f038-bb35-438f-a9ca-2ca8b649dea4",
      "oid": "2755d0c4-19ab-495e-9441-4ae6fe87e17a",
      "preferred_username": "testUser1@mybusinessname.onmicrosoft.com",
      "sub": "WcB02vJDa7vzfgWbJTY8m604eYhGosphCmr569Wc7Yc",
      "tid": "04d8c97b-25df-4533-b5fe-197f0117556c",
      "uti": "mC5BVa6fukuEXIVB5jJYAA",
      "ver": "2.0"
    }.[Signature]
```

5. Not sure if it's relevant, but here's my MSAL config:

```js
    @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: '0af5e22c-1233-470f-b2a8-e47038c69524', // Azure B2C ID for my angular web client, 'mybusinessname-web-dev'.
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mybusinessname.onmicrosoft.com",
      redirectUri: "https://localhost:4200/", 
      cacheLocation : "sessionStorage",
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://localhost:4200/",
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      unprotectedResources: ["https://localhost:4200/"],
      popUp: true,
      validateAuthority: false
    })
```

Appreciate any help possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token has got nothing to do with this error.
The issue is possibly wrt certifcate on the hosting service. Using network tools/fiddler it will be helpful to understand which extact call returns TLS errors. If the call to get a token is returning it, it would be a B2C issue else it would be an issue with the endpoint where your service is hosted.

You can follow this as well [TLS issues on Chrome](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-fix-err-ssl-protocol-error)

Comment: This is embarrassing.  I cut and pasted and left the "s" on my localhost, "httpS: localhost:4200". Except I don't have a cert for my local dev machine, and so it can't handle TLS. 
So the full answer is that a secure connection with MSAL-angular/B2C will fail if your host doesn't use secure connections at all. 

In my defense, I did try many changes, for a several days, before resorting to posting a question here. So I'm not lazy, just stupid. :) Thanks for the help.